# How to use Azure Databricks to run ML programs with multiple files and modules?

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks

I know how to run a Machine learning program in a single notebook. But how do I run if there are multiple files and dependencies. How do I run this [code](https://github.com/iliaschalkidis/lmtc-eurlex57k). Any ideas in this case?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for installing notebook-scoped libraries:

- Using the `%pip` or `%conda` magic command in the notebook. The `%pip`
  command is supported in [Databricks Runtime 7.1](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/7.1.html) and above. Both
  `%pip` and `%conda` are supported in Databricks Runtime 6.4 ML and above.
  This article describes how to use these magic commands.

[image]

- Using Databricks library utilities. This is supported only on
  Databricks Runtime, not Databricks Runtime ML. See [Library utilities](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-library).

[image]

**Reference:** [Notebook-scoped Python libraries](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html#notebook-scoped-python-libraries)

**OR**

Specify your library requirements in one notebook and install them through `%run` in the other.
Define the libraries to install in a notebook called **InstallDependencies**.

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("torch")
dbutils.library.installPyPI("scikit-learn", version="1.19.1")
dbutils.library.installPyPI("azureml-sdk", extras="databricks")
dbutils.library.restartPython()  # Removes Python state, but some libraries might not work without calling this function
```

Install them in the notebook that needs those dependencies.

```
%run /path/to/InstallDependencies    # Install the dependencies in first cell
```

**Reference:** [Databricks - Notebook library Utilities](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#library-utilities)